# Handler on userIcon (IconCls) of Extjs Menu is not working in Mozilla browser ExtJs 6.0.2.437

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am facing a issue regarding Extjs Menu. When we click on user icon (iconCls)then handler of menu is not working in Mozilla browser.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29vm

Comment: Can you tell properly what is issue in fiddle.Because On menu wherever I am clicking it is getting closed.

Comment: @Tejas when you click on Icon in mozila browser then handler is not fired.

Comment: which mozilla browser, as its working absolutely fine with me.Mention other details like version.

Comment: @Tejas mozilla firefox 52.0.2. Also check your extjs version it is not working in ExtJs 6.0.2.437. but worked in higher versions

Comment: I can't see this issue... does your computer have a touchscreen?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes When you click on user icon in Mozilla browser then handler of menu item is not fired.